# Trackpad on Thinkpad X1 Carbon Gen 6 (2018) Randomly Stops Working and Dissapears (Fedora 38)

Tags: linux, fedora, touchpad, thinkpad, synaptic

I've been researching this problem for a while but none of the proposed solutions seemed to have helped. I tried disabling the trackpoint in Bios and added "psmouse.synaptics_intertouch=1" to my grub file but neither worked. For some context I'm running Fedora 38 and all my firmware is up to date. I have the 20KH model which usually doesn't have this problem for other owners. My output from dmesg is as follows: [image]. Apologies ahead of time if this is something very obvious, I'm new to Linux. I'd really appreciate any help as I've been stuck with this for more than a week.

Comment: please dont insert images of text

Comment: what does "CUTS OUT" mean?

Comment: Sorry, by cuts out I mean it completely stops working and the cursor dissapears from the screen.